# Mismatch Between Transactions and Sessions in DMVs sys.dm_tran_session_transactions and sys.dm_tran_database_transactions

Tags: sql-server, transaction, session

I've been working with several Dynamic Management Views (DMVs) in SQL Server to monitor transactions, specifically `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions`, `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions`, and `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`.

I understand that `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions` is used to match sessions and transactions, but I've noticed some inconsistencies. There are instances where I can identify a transaction from `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions` or `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`, but I'm unable to find the corresponding session from the `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions` DMV.

Why would this occur? Are there certain transactions, perhaps internal ones, that don't have corresponding session IDs? Any insight into this behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

### Update

You can use below two queries to easily find a lot of such mismatched session IDs.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st
        ON st.transaction_id = at.transaction_id
WHERE st.session_id IS NULL;


SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_database_transactions dt
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st
        ON st.transaction_id = dt.transaction_id
WHERE st.session_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: What are the values of `database_transaction_type` and `database_transaction_state` for those rows?

Comment: @Charlieface they are 2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: @Charlieface I've added two queries and you can easily find some such sessions. I tested  on several systems and all of them reported some such sessions.

Comment: Well 3 is a system transaction. And the other ones I see on my system refer to worktables, which are also generated by the system.